How to solve the response of my terminal that works very slow and badly?
The problem is that my terminals not work great anymore.
The typing is very bad in terminal and each command response not if I press a key.
Sometimes the command runs but it ends not, but when I hit enter the prompt comes back, if I think the command should be done.
So, what I have done to solve my problem, but still not figured out what the problem is.
# System up to date and some software repaired and missing packages reinstalled.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-software gsettings-desktop-schemas gconf2
sudo apt-get install -f

I check the journal and found some errors and cleared it with the commands above.
sudo journalctl -x

The issue with the terminals without any config files still present.
env -i bash --noprofile --norc

export TERM=xterm
export TERM=linux
export TERM=xterm-256color

# The exports needed if they do not there htop or ranger would not run.

# Debugging is also not shows up errors.
bash -x

# Result is alright - no errors found
sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda

The work with these apps is absolute not good anymore.
The refresh of the programs output is only possible with a key hit.
tmux
htop
ranger
apt-get
etc.

That is my snap list if it is important for my problem.
snap list --all
Name Version
bare 1.0
chromium 123.0.6312.86
chromium-ffmpeg 0.1
core 16-2.61.2
core18 20231027
core20 20240111
core22 20240111
cups 2.4.7-3
docker 24.0.5
firefox 124.0.1-1
gnome-3-26-1604 3.26.0.20221130
gnome-3-28-1804 3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67
gnome-3-34-1804 0+git.3556cb3
gnome-3-38-2004 0+git.efb213a
gnome-42-2204 0+git.510a601
gnome-system-monitor 45.0
gtk-common-themes 0.1-81-g442e511
hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004 1.7-20.04+pkg-6fd6
mesa-core20 21.2.6
snap-store 41.3-77-g7dc86c8
snapd-desktop-integration 0.9

I downloaded the latest Ubuntu 22.04.4 Desktop iso and made a Live-USB.
In the live system is not this issue.
So. What kind of error I missing? Or what I forget to check?

I just came here to post a question about the shell / terminal literally stopping while I'm typing.  I can type two letters in the terminal and a space and the space takes 1 second to appear.   I have 16GB ram, running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (been running it since it came out, before that was running 22.04.3).  Nothing has changed on the system, but the terminal shell typing is so annoying right now.  No idea what is going on.

Perhaps something in this recent Q&A will be helpful: input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4

Same here, this is quite recent (a week or so). i suspect nvidia drivers for some reason. my system is a ryzen 9 3900x, 64 gb ram ddr4, clean install. odd thing: using alacritty terminal everything works fine.

If you have solved your problem, please post an answer, instead of editing the question

Thanks @muru I made it as answer.

Solution for the issue:
Useful tip from: Perhaps something in this recent Q&A will be helpful:
input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4 – steeldriver
Tipp:
But after this fix - The system is in a bad shape. What I mean is apt-get install could not install or remove any programs anymore, because of the changed packages!
# Ubuntu package assistent says call these command.
# But do not it otherwise, it will removing gdm gnome-desktop etc.
# Than the desktop enviroment is gone - unbeliveable I saw that - I sayed NO!
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install

# To come back into normal state follow below "Undo the script with these commands:"
# This is a save way to come back into a working system with apt-get!

The issue is the mutter package:

ii libmutter-10-0:amd64 42.9-0ubuntu7 amd64
ii mutter-common 42.9-0ubuntu7 all

Terminal works normal as aspected after replaceing it with these:

hi libmutter-10-0:amd64 42.0-3ubuntu2 amd64
ii mutter-common 42.0-3ubuntu2 all

Undo the script with these commands:
sudo apt-mark unhold $(apt-mark showhold)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mutter-common libmutter-10-0

The script from the comment with little changes here:
# I modified the script a little bit, 
# because there was some changed need, 
# otherwise Ubuntu 22.04.4 would cry like a baby because wrong version.
# 
# Important after running the script - A restart of the OS is needed!
# 
# Skript begins - I run it in a bash-Shell
arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) # one of amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x

ubuntuVersion=$(grep -i "distrib_release" /etc/lsb-release | cut -sd '=' -f2)

version=""
package=""

if [[ "${ubuntuVersion}" = "23.10" ]]; then
    # Ubuntu 23.10
    version="45.0-3ubuntu3"
    package="13-0"
fi

if [[ "${ubuntuVersion}" = "23.04" ]]; then
    # Ubuntu 23.04
    if [[ "${arch}" = "amd64" ]]; then
        version="44.3-0ubuntu1.1" # only amd64
    else
        version="44.0-2ubuntu4" # other archs
    fi
    package="12-0"
fi

if [[ "${ubuntuVersion}" = "22.04" ]]; then
    # Ubuntu 22.04
    version="42.0-3ubuntu2"
    package="10-0"
fi

if [[ -z "${package}" || -z "${version}" ]]; then
    echo "Error - Package or Version not set"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ -n "$( dpkg -l | grep 'mutter' | grep ''${version}'' )" ]]; then
    # Found older version and replace it with the new one
    echo libmutter-${package} install | sudo dpkg --set-selections
    echo libmutter-common install | sudo dpkg --set-selections

    # Reinstall the newer packages of the mutter package
    if [ "${package}" != "10-0" ]; then
      echo libmutter-common-bin install | sudo dpkg --set-selections
      sudo apt-get install --reinstall mutter-common libmutter-10-0 libmutter-common-bin
    else
      sudo apt-get install --reinstall mutter-common libmutter-10-0
    fi

else
    # Replace the newer version with the older ones
    wget http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mutter/libmutter-${package}_${version}_$arch.deb
    wget http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mutter/mutter-common_${version}_all.deb
    if [ "${package}" != "10-0" ]; then
      wget http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mutter/mutter-common-bin_${version}_$arch.deb
    fi

    sudo dpkg -i *mutter*.deb

    echo libmutter-${package} hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
    echo libmutter-common hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
    if [ "${package}" != "10-0" ]; then
      echo libmutter-common-bin hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
    fi
fi
# Skript ends

